# Adding two ListViews to a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am doing a time management app for android for my project in school. So there is a class called Activity which represents the activities done by the user through the day(Like going to school,listening to music,eating etc). Activity objects have an instant variable called done which is type of boolean and another insant variable Tags which is a Tag array. There is need for boolean done because user can enter activities for the future and later he/she can mark it as done. Tag class is for the user to label their activities(For example an activity can have tags: sport and hobby at the same time).These activities entered by the user to the program are shown in a fragment called Activities fragment. There will be 2 different Listviews in this fragment one for done and the other for undone activities. So I wrote my xml code so that it would have 2 Listviews on top of each other and added this listviews to my fragment. However, when I run my code I only can see one of the Listviews, the other one does not show up.This is how my xml file look like:(here is the picture of the design:http://postimg.org/image/a7u1ynfzb/)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.beter.timehole.fragment.ActivitiesFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
     />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code for fragment class:

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends Fragment {

public ActivitiesFragment() {
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<Tag> tags1= new ArrayList<Tag>();
    tags1.add(new Tag("Tag1"));

    ArrayList<Tag> tags2= new ArrayList<Tag>();
    tags2.add(new Tag("Tag2"));

    com.beter.timehole.core.Activity doneSample = new com.beter.timehole.core.Activity("Work",true,70,"16 50","17 00",tags1,"did it");
    com.beter.timehole.core.Activity undoneSample = new com.beter.timehole.core.Activity("Fun",false,30,"13 30","14 00",tags2,"will do it");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);
    ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity> doneActivities = new ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>();
    doneActivities.add(doneSample);
    ListView doneList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    doneList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, doneActivities));

    ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity> undoneActivities = new ArrayList<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>();
    undoneActivities.add(undoneSample);
    ListView undoneList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    undoneList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<com.beter.timehole.core.Activity>(getActivity(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,undoneActivities));
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Change the ListViews' `layout_height`s to `0dp`.

Comment: Add `android:weightSum=2` in  `LinearLayout ` and both ListView `layout_height` to `0dp ` then try it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The `weightSum` isn't necessary.

Comment: changing listViews' heights to 0 did not help and neither the android:weightSum="2"

Answer (score 3):

Try to Change layout_height="0dp" .

Try this layout code.

`

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

`

If this is not working try to check your code or put your complete code here.

Comment: In this case the result did not change. I only see the undone Listview in the middle of the page.Thank you for your help. Plese let me know if you understand the problem.

Comment: ya sure i have a doubt what is `com.beter.timehole.core.Activity` in your java code.

Comment: That is the reference to Activity class I created,  when I wrote only activity the program could not find it so I wrote it in this way.

Comment: I do not think activity class is problematic it creates the objects properly and in ListView2 I can see the object I created but I will share the source code anyway in case there are any problems. I will share it after 7-8 hours when I will arrive home.

Comment: OK no issue ... But try to first check listview1 with data and same as 2 separately. And let me know the issue

Comment: Actually today I found out that the toolbar was blocking the first item which is added to the first listView so there is only need for a top margin to listView1 one other than that the code should work fine but I have changed the design there completely, so thank you very much for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.beter.timehole.fragment.ActivitiesFragment">
        <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
         />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
         /></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this case None of the List views showed up. There were some letters at very top of the page.However I could only see bottom part of the letters. So I could not understand which Listview was that. Thank you for your help. Plese let me know if you understand the problem.

Comment: I can help, If you can share the complete xml code of yur layout

Comment: Actually that is the complete one this layout only has 2 listviews in it and that is all.

Comment: I have already tried this one, it did not help and I also tried relative layout and add 'android:layout_below:"@+id\listView1" to my second list view but it did not work, too. I could only see the second listView again.

Comment: Actually today I found out that the toolbar was blocking the first item which is added to the first listView so there is only need for a top margin to listView1 one other than that the code should work fine but I have changed the design there completely, so thank you very much for your help I appreciate it.